# How to store dynamic localized strings

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, localization, internationalization

I'm using laravel framework and mysql to build a site which needs to be translated into, at the moment 3 but it may increase, different languages. Using Laravel it is relatively easy to create different language files for different languages and call them in the html for relatively static strings. However, for data coming out of a database, what is the best practice for localizing such data? It seems that storing the localized versions of the strings would work well in the sense that they can all be added at the same time as the data is created; however, it seems it would be horrible in the sense of adding a new language. Using language files for the data seems better for adding new languages, but would be annoying to keep up with when new rows are added to the database.
I've come up with a solution to translate some of the data in a relatively static selectbox (it uses a static array of ids/names of some of the most common data) so that users may be able to utilize that part of the site pretty well no matter the language, but the data as it shows up on the rest of the site is naturally unaffected by that change.

What is the best practice for handling such an issue? The few solutions I can come up with all seem rather flawed.

Note: the new rows are added on a management site which is separate from the main site, but shares the same data in the database. The people adding the new rows would not have direct access to any language files.

Comment: I don't see why you don't want to use language files? I won't store it in a DB merely because of the overhead you will encounter: imagine for each page request you will need to fetch the words from the DB (unless you're caching it in some way).

Comment: I didn't exactly say I was against using language files. It's just at some points in time some of the items can increase by hundreds in one day. Those entering the data have no direct access to language files on the main site, so managing them in that sense seems difficult to me, unless there is some good way I am just completely unaware of.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, you can try something like Laravel Translation - https://github.com/Waavi/translation

Comment: So you're saying that the new entries could be added to that language table at the time of entry, and using this, they could be easily called? It does seem nice in that sense, but calling

php artisan translator:load (which would likely be needed to update strings on the site itself)

would cause those entries to be lost, wouldn't it?